# How to set correct comma position in html

Tags: html, css

#### Steps to replicate issue:

1. go to the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/140wnd2p/)

```html
<div class="project-authors">
        <a class="overflow contributor-name" rel="tooltip" href="/mzxef/" data-original-title="Haoyu Chen">Chen</a>
<span>,</span>
        <a class="overflow contributor-name" rel="tooltip" href="/snmp9/" data-original-title="Test2 Chen">Chen</a>
<span>&amp;</span>
        <a class="overflow contributor-name" rel="tooltip" href="/jtphc/" data-original-title="test">test</a>
<span></span>
</div>
```

2. Run the code and get text.

#### Expected

[image]

#### Actual

[image]

How can I let the comma in the right(expected) position. Thanks in advance

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. SO also has the ability to embed runnable HTML/CSS/JavaScript snippets in questions like jsFiddle.

Comment: also you need to fix the link. it's broken

Comment: @j08691 that may be true, but JSFiddle is a significantly better tool for the job of running and debugging example code, SO have a way to go yet before they catch up! the code should always be posted in the question though

Comment: You probably have a space after "Chen".  Even in HTML between elements , a space is a space

Comment: @ToniLeigh - That's a matter of opinion, however my point to the OP is that they should always place their code in your question, and optionally supplement with an example even if it's on a third party site like jsFiddle.

Comment: @j08691 Actually, this is the new rule for me. In the past, I always used a link to jsfiddle and it worked fine. Now stackoverflow forces other to put code in its own website.

Comment: @j08691 yeah it's still a work in progress, but it's feature set is limited in comparison to both JSFiddle and CodePen

Comment: I just want to express my angry that people are eager to judge others. Push so many down votes and didn't give me time to refine it!...

Comment: @HaoyuChen - actually SO just requires an example piece of code along with a link to a JSFiddle, this is fair enough, it leaves the question complete should JSFiddle ever disappear, however, for an example building and debugging tool JSFiddle and CodePen are streets ahead

Comment: @ToniLeigh OK, I got it! Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the line break between the link and the `span` (see the [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apf44ppk/)).

```
<a class="overflow contributor-name" rel="tooltip" href="/mzxef/" data-original-title="Haoyu Chen">Chen</a><span>,</span>
```

Also, kind of strange that you would be putting a comma in its own `span`, unless you have a very specific purpose for it. If not, I would recommend getting rid of that altogether.